# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send a mail from spring application. I have included all the jar files but it is showing this exception:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:1611)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1369)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:412)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:310)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
    at org.symb.leavemanagement.mail.SampleMail.sentMail(SampleMail.java:65)
    at org.symb.leavemanagement.controller.AdminController.processRegistratingUser(AdminController.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:175)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:421)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:409)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:774)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(InputRecord.java:541)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:374)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:893)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1294)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:848)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
    at com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:110)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
    at com.sun.mail.util.LineInputStream.readLine(LineInputStream.java:88)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:1589)
    ... 38 more
```

Comment: Why was this reopened? It's a duplicate.

Answer (score 8):

You are trying to do an SSL connection to a non SSL end-point. If you change that it should work.

I've found that most tutorials about integrating your email with Outlook/Thunderbird/etc call SSL/TSL to a non SSL connection. In general what I've found out there (and this can change but it's the norm) is that only smtp port 465 is SSL. 587 is TSL (no SSL) and 25 is plain.

Comment: "TLS (no SSL)" is essentially meaningless. An SMTPS connection is secured by SSL or TLS. The reservation of 465 for SMTPS was [revoked in 1998](http://www.imc.org/ietf-apps-tls/mail-archive/msg00204.html) although it is still in use for backwards compatibility reasons. The real difference between 465 and 587 is that 587 supports the STARTTLS command and therefore both plaintext and TLS/SSL.